# How to customise logging in tapir?

Tags: scala, tapir

I'm sure this is a ridiculous question... I'm trying to enable tapir's logging as described here:

https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/v0.19.0-m4/server/debugging.html

... but even having looked at the ServerOptions docs, I'm not getting anywhere. My naive assumption from the docs was that it should be something like:

```
import sttp.tapir.server.akkahttp.AkkaHttpServerOptions
import sttp.tapir.server.interceptor.log.DefaultServerLog

val customServerOptions: AkkaHttpServerOptions = AkkaHttpServerOptions.customInterceptors(
    serverLog = DefaultServerLog(logWhenHandled=true, logAllDecodeFailures=true)
)
```

and then

```
AkkaHttpServerInterpreter(customServerOptions).toRoute(...)
```

However, this is clearly way off - `DefaultServerLog` is the wrong type, and would need masses of configuration.

The docs imply this can just be done by setting a few flags, what am I missing?

Comment: are you using 0.19.0-M4 in your project? that's quite an old version

Comment: Yes. It's a project I recently inherited (I'm completely new to tapir, and indeed akka). So yes, upgrading would be a good thing to do - I'd just rather it wasn't a last-day-before-Christmas problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DefaultServerLog` is the default implementation for the `ServerLog` trait, though it has a couple of fields without default values. These fields specify how to actually perform the logging: `DefaultServerLog .doLogWhenHandled` etc.

What you need to do is to get an instance of `DefaultServerLog`, which is configured to integrate with akka-http. This is available as `AkkaHttpServerOptions.Log.defaultServerLog`.

Unfortunately, in 0.19 this was typed too narrowly, not allowing proper customisation. Hence, an ugly cast is needed (this is fixed in the current, stable 1.2 version):

```scala
val customServerOptions: AkkaHttpServerOptions = 
  AkkaHttpServerOptions.customInterceptors(
    serverLog = Some(
      AkkaHttpServerOptions.Log.defaultServerLog
        .asInstanceOf[DefaultServerLog[LoggingAdapter => Future[Unit]]]
        .copy(logWhenHandled = true, logAllDecodeFailures = true)
    )
  )

AkkaHttpServerInterpreter(customServerOptions).toRoute(???)
```

As for the docs, you are right that they might be misleading (they haven't changed much since 0.19), I'll fix that shortly.

Comment: Here's the commit fixing the docs: https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir/commit/cd60ac941d047b3207fe11c3491d9ca7cc80a910